# Add To Basket Function Not Working

Tags: jquery, clone, addition

I Have Created A simple J Query Add to Basket Function. However Not Everything works as it should. Everything works for the first item so if I press add to basket the item is added and if I target the same product the qty is changed instead. However the problem comes when I try to add a second product to the basket it just keeps adding and adding on the second product almost as it is not present in the basket.

```
$(".atb").click(function() {
    $("#basket-pop").addClass("show");
    $("#bsc").addClass("hide");    
    var nju = $("#img-block").find("img").attr("src");

    if ($("ul.testBas li").find("img").attr("src") == ("#")) {
        $("#prod-space").find("img").attr("src", nju);
        var cos = $(".qty-num").val();
        $(".prod-qty").empty();
        $(".prod-qty").append(cos);       
    }

    if ($("ul.testBas li").find("img").attr("src") == (nju)) {
        var cos = $(".qty-num").val();
        $(".prod-qty").empty();
        $(".prod-qty").append(cos);
    }

    if ($("ul.testBas li").find("img").attr("src") != (nju)) {
        var niu = $('ul.testBas li:last-child').clone();
        $(niu).appendTo("ul.testBas");
        $(niu).find("img").attr("src", nju);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're not targetting anything whatsoever. So `var cos = $(".qty-num").val();` will find the *first* element with that class, probably not the correct element. Provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue, and ill show you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`var cos` is a String . You can not append element `.prod-qty` to it.

content in `$(selector).append(content)` is Required. Specifies the content to insert (can contain HTML tags) and Possible values:

1) HTML elements

2)jQuery objects

3)DOM elements